# closing a previously opened socket

Tags: python, sockets

I created a program which listens to particular socket in python, however I ctrl+c'd script which resulted in .close() nor called, however how can I free the socket now.

Comment: Are you asking how can free the socket now? Or how can you free the socket if the termination signal is recd.?

Answer (score 3):

The *socket* is closed when the process exits. The *port* it was using may hang around for a couple of minutes, that's normal, then it will disappear. If you need to re-use the port immediately, set SO_REUSEADDR before binding or connecting.

Comment: can you explain how to do SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: @VaibhavMishra Why? It's well documented. That would just be repeating someone else's work. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option before calling the `bind` method, like this:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

That will instruct the socket to freely reuse the ports left in a waiting state by recent runs of the program.

Or, use the `SocketServer.TCPServer` class from the standard library, which will automatically do this if you set the `allow_reuse_address` property on the server instance to a true value.